# reCAPTCHA preventing me from accessing business website on a local network

Tags: recaptcha

I have been facing issue with regards to reCAPTCHA preventing from access our daily business websites on our local network. Not sure what caused this but it has been asking for security challenge which is not even completed and fails authentication.

Not sure if this is something to do with the network, website backend, or hosting provider.

[Photo of error](https://prnt.sc/mjaapb)

carremoval.co.nz / scrapmycar.co.nz / 4wdwreckers.co.nz /  topcashforcars.co.nz

I have tried:

- restarting the router.
- Running `ipconfig /flushdns`
- even in incognito, it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried `ipconfig /release` and then run `ipconfig /renew`. If that doesn't work you could try `ipconfig /registerdns`

Comment: Also, take a look at [this Google forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/9SOdj1y87Wc)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `ipconfig /release` and then run `ipconfig /renew`. If that doesn't work you could try `ipconfig /registerdns`

Also, try these steps: [Taken from here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/9SOdj1y87Wc)

1. Clear your cache and cookies.
2. Disable browser extensions one by one and see if this helps resolve the issue.
3. Try resetting your modem or router.
4. If you are using a VPN, try uninstalling VPN browser plugin or program.
5. Check your computer for Malware.

If none of this works your next step should be to disable your antivirus and turn off your firewall.

> In the case of the OP he confronted his hosting provider and their system had listed his WAN IP on their cachewall. When they removed it all was working fine.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried all the steps. Before these, i managed one of the sites to open on Mozilla Firefox. But the same website doesn't open on Chrome. I did talk to my ISP as well but they say DNS is all good.

Comment: @NationalCarRemoval Shucks. Did you try turning off your antivirus, and disabling your firewall?

Comment: Cutwow appreciate your help. I confronted my hosting provided one more time and their system listed our WAN IP on the cachewall. They removed it and its working fine now. Thank you so much.